# Advanced Sql query solution required

Tags: sql

```
player       team           start_date   end_date  points
John Jacob   SportsBallers  2015-01-01  2015-03-31  100
John Jacob   SportsKings    2015-04-01  2015-12-01  115
Joe Smith    PointScorers   2014-01-01  2016-12-31  125
Bill Johnson SportsKings    2015-01-01  2015-06-31  175
Bill Johnson AllStarTeam    2015-07-01  2016-12-31  200
```

The above table has many more rows. I was asked the below questions in an interview.

> 1.)For each player, which team were they play for on 2015-01-01?

I could not answer this one.

> 2.)For each player, how can we get the team for whom they scored the most points?

```
select team from Players
where points in (select max(points) from players group by player).
```

Please, solutions for both.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

```
select *  
from PlayerTeams  
where startdate <='2015-01-01' and enddate >= '2015-01-01'
```

## 2

```
Select player, team, points  
from(  
Select *, row_number() over (partition by player order by points desc) as rank  
From PlayerTeams) as player  
where rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For #1:

```
Select Player
      ,Team
From table
Where '2015-01-01' between start_date and end_date
```

For #2:

```
select t.Player
      ,t.Team
from table t
inner join (select Player
                  ,Max(points)
            from table
            group by Player) m
   on t.Player = m.Player
   and t.points = m.points
```

Comment: select team from Players
where points in (select max(points) from players group by player) - Is this wrong?

Comment: Hi Degan...Thanks for your response. I have a doubt in first query can we write a query in such a way "Where '2015-01-01' between start_date and end_date " . I have always written queries like " Where Start_date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-03-01'

Comment: Yes, you can write a query, "Where '2015-01-01' between start_date and end_date ".  Your "select team from Players where points in (select max(points) from players group by player)" query will find the teams that have a player who scored the same number of points of any players maximum points.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: But isnt your 2nd query doing the same? Why is there an extra need of join. 
 t.Player = m.Player
   and t.points = m.points